# Asymptotics of ratio of q-Pochhammer symbols

Tags: infinite-product, hypergeometric-function, q-series, pochhammer-symbol

In (9.23) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.08875 , they claim that it is "easy" to show the following limits $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{(yq^\frac{2-r+m}{2};q)_\infty}{(y^{-1}q^\frac{r+m}{2};q)_\infty}=\lim_{y\to \infty}(-y)^mq^\frac{(1-r)m}{2}\frac{(yq^\frac{2-r+m}{2};q)_\infty}{(y^{-1}q^\frac{r+m}{2};q)_\infty}=1\,,\quad r,m\in\mathbb{Z}\,,\quad (z;q)\equiv\prod_{k=0}^\infty(1-zq^k)\,.$$

Is this true? If so, I would be grateful for hints to prove it. Numerical tests suggest that the first limit is false. I'm inclined to say that $$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{(yq^\frac{2-r+m}{2};q)_\infty}{(y^{-1}q^\frac{r+m}{2};q)_\infty}=\frac{1}{\infty}=0\,.$$

Comment: In what realm are the limits being computed (complex variables, formal power series, something more exotic)? In terms of complex variables, I don't think the first limit (equals 1) will work out. However, I also don't think the denominator goes off to infinity, it looks more like an essential singularity to me.

Comment: Also minor typo in the second limit, the factor out front should be $q^{\frac{(1-r)m}{2}}$?

Comment: @ChrisJS Thanks for the typo. I would be interested as long as the limit is correct in some sense. How do you know that the denominator has an essential singularity rather than diverging as $y^{-n}$?

Comment: Looking at just $(y^{-1}q^{\frac{r+m}{2}};q)_\infty$, I see infinitely many divide by zeros, which suggests an essential singularity or something worse. This product does have zeros clustering as $y\rightarrow0$, which is definitely a problem (take $y$ along the sequence $y_N=q^{N-\frac{r+m}{2}}$), but that's messy because infinite products diverge to 0 (instead of converge to 0).

Comment: To make this limit sound even more suspicious, consider that $(yq^{1-\frac{r+m}{2}},q;q)_\infty$ is holomorphic at y=0 and $(y^{-1}q^{\frac{r+m}{2}},yq^{1-\frac{r+m}{2}},q;q)_\infty$ has a series expansion by the Jacobi triple product identity with non-zero coefficients of $y^n$ for all integers $n$.  Unrelated, but the authors have defined $(a;q)_{n}$ for negative $n$ incorrectly in equation 6.25; it should be 1 over the product they write (their version is what people sometimes first guess, but it's wrong for functional equations).

Comment: This is only a wild guess, but if the limit does work out in any sense, it might follow by taking the triple product I wrote above, view it as a theta function, and use asymptotics for theta functions (not my specialty).

Comment: @ChrisJS Interesting, I was not aware of the Jacobi triple product. It might indeed be useful.